# Is there a reason to include a tracking code on a page, no script, just the code itself?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

On a CMS that I administer, all of the pages are under a single domain. We have google analytics installed on most pages on the domain, but we do not allow individual users to add their own analytics to their pages, namely because we do not allow any custom html/script to be added. One of our users has registered their own analytics account for their site, and they are including the tracking code, as plaintext, just below their content. It is intentional on their part. **Is there any legitimate reason to do this?** ie,

> This is my page. 
>  Welcome. 
>  Tracking ID: UA-7xxxxxxx-1

Comment: Can you please paste the sample script/text on page you are talking about?

Comment: @abhinsit there is no script/code. It is essentially what I have posted, specifically it is a short biography, with the "Tracking ID" line just below it.

Answer (score 4):

No,
This will not solve any purpose for your user.
For proper analytics to work, they have to add the complete tracking code which is javascript

OR

As you said the google analytics script is already on page, they would have added a GA push event which again would have been javascript.

But since you don't allow javascript, they can't/shouldn't do it

For more understanding or debugging there is a **chrome extension : google analytics debugger** that you can add to chrome and see all analytics interaction on your page. This will help you identify any malicious use of script/text on your page.

Comment: makes sense! just checking since they are insistant it remain there